# Объединить и синонимизировать метки [google-spreadsheet] и [googlesheets]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток

Нужно объединить метки

- [google-spreadsheet](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet) - 271 вопрос;
- [googlesheets](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/googlesheets) - 224 вопроса.

Основная метка - [google-spreadsheet](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Синонимизировал, вопросы перенёс

[googlesheets](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/googlesheets) → [google-spreadsheet](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet)